# dojo style developement

Tags: javascript, dojo, closures

I'm having difficulty wrapping my head around dojo style of coding. The reason I am drawn to it is because of its class style coding. I have done AS developement and some java so it makes sense to me to be drawn to it. I have done some jquery style DOM work but I require a more framework based setup for a project I'm starting.
My question is should I be creating everything as classes with the declare and then requiring them when needed. Or could I write closure type functions with namespaces just like regular javascript modules. I'm confused.

Example I want to have a group of methods that take care of managing data. Then I want to have another collection of methods that handle special ajax calls. Would I create a class with declare for each of these groups of methods, in separate js files. Then in my app.js which is my application class where I'm handling the initialization of all my classes, would I require both those classes before dojo.ready(){}
then once the ready method is called I can start to use those classes.

Can someone set me straight here before I dojo out.
Does require make a load request for that js file and if so do you always have to use the ready method. If so is it best to require a bunch of your classes up front at the start of your application initialization.

Comment: No dojo people, anyone out there that can answer some of these questions?

Comment: Jeez man, an hour (edit: sorry, 3 hours; still applies) isn't very long to wait for an answer ;) I'll write one up now.

Comment: Hey Ken sorry to sound pushy but I'm a little frustrated reading through hours and hours of the same docs that don't fully explain my questions, or maybe they do and I'm not getting it. I have even been trying to find examples of Util classes where you don't have to instantiate them. Seems like its either declare it and call it with the new myClass, which sometimes I'm  just looking to create a util or helper class that I can call publicly. If you have the time to answer some of my questions above that would be great. Again sorry if I came across as impatient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically for what you're wanting to do, you could go either way - using `dojo.declare` or simply creating an object with function members.  I'd be inclined to do the latter, since `dojo.declare`'s elaborate inheritance considerations will be total overkill that you won't be making use of in this case, and it doesn't generally make sense to be instantiating anything when you just want to group some utility methods together.

For modules that simply group utility methods together, I'd be inclined to do something along these lines:

```
dojo.provide('my.utils');

my.utils = {
    doSomething: function(){
        /* do something... */
    },

    doSomethingElse: function(){
        /* do something else... */
    }
};
```

RE loading, if I'm reading you right, then yes, you have the right idea.  In your web page, you would `dojo.require(...)` the modules your page requires (perhaps just one, if you have all your other dependencies further required within it).  Then, any code in the page that expects these modules to be loaded should be within a function passed to `dojo.ready`.  This ensures that even in cases where modules are asynchronously loaded (i.e. using the cross-domain loader), your code will still work.  `dojo.ready` specifically waits for (1) the DOM to be ready and (2) all `dojo.require`d modules up to that point to be loaded.

Note that within modules themselves, you do NOT need to enclose code in `dojo.ready` for the sake of waiting for `dojo.require`d modules to load; this is figured out by the loader automatically.  (However, if some logic in your module needs to wait for the DOM to be ready, you would still rely upon `dojo.ready`.)

I've written more about `dojo.ready` in the past; maybe it'll be a helpful read: http://kennethfranqueiro.com/2010/08/dojo-required-reading/

Comment: Thanks Ken for your detailed post. so is this typical style if you don't need to the extra functionality of declare. Could you also use closure functions and other patterns of javascript and assign them in a namespace and still have them load with the require() method. Just want to make sure I don't start writing all sorts of patterns when its bad practice. A lot of the time I don't need to use the object more than once so no need for instantiating it.

Comment: You could ostensibly assign whatever you want to `my.utils` within that module and it'd be fine.  Yes, it's not uncommon to place the body of the module within an immediately-invoked function expression to create a closure for you to work with.